# Custom Images as map

Tags: python, image, dictionary

http://macwright.org/2012/08/13/images-as-maps.html

I am studying about this link and i got trouble

"This is a Python script: download it as a raw file, name it togeo.py. You’ll need GDAL for it to work – not necessarily the ‘python bindings’, but make sure that, in your terminal, gdal_translate and gdalinfo are present."

I dont know how to make "gdal_translate and gdalinfo are present in terminal",
can anyone help me about that?

**here is the error msg when i run "python togeo.py eso1119a.jpg":**

```
Janes-MacBook-Pro:desktop kennett$ python togeo.py eso1119a.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "togeo.py", line 7, in <module>
    info_output = subprocess.Popen(['gdalinfo', infile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you just need to install gdal and make sure that the executables are on your PATH environment variable.  If you can, it's probably easiest if you can get it from a package manager.  How you do this is platform specific.  Otherwise, you can always install from source.  The source code is available from http://www.gdal.org/

Comment: i have add the error msg into my question, is that any problem about my installation?

Comment: Yes it is.  Brew failed while trying to install gdal.  I'd recommend trying downloading the .dmg file from here http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Complete-1.10.dmg and try to use that to install instead.

Comment: thanks i have install it successfully ,but another question apply...i  add it into the question now

Comment: Hmm, it probably still isn't installed successfully.  If you type "gdalinfo" on the terminal what output do you get?  If it's working you should get something like this: Usage: gdalinfo [--help-general] [-mm] [-stats] [-hist] [-nogcp] [-nomd]
                [-norat] [-noct] [-nofl] [-checksum] [-proj4] [-mdd domain]*
                [-sd subdataset] datasetname

Comment: Janes-MacBook-Pro:desktop kennett$ gdalinfo
-bash: gdalinfo: command not found

Comment: Yes, it looks like something went wrong with the gdal installation.  The error that you're getting is because python tries to call "gdalinfo", but the program is not available.

Comment: i think it's probably not installed successful, but by the dmg, it told me that it install successfully...poor me

Comment: thanks anyway, i will go search more about this bugs, and if u have any idea, please feel free to tell me:)

Comment: OK, sounds good.  You might want to make sure that you have the dependencies, and that the executable is on your path.  I *think* that you can add the executables to your path like this, but it depends where gdal got installed: export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH

Comment: the $PATH works!!!!!!!!!! i can create a tiff successfully!!!!! thanks a lot!!!!!